# Scala: Cannot resolve symbol in function

Tags: scala

I want to reimplement again scala left/right/either. Here is my code:

```
case class Left[+E](get: E) extends Either[E, Nothing]

case class Right[+A](get: A) extends Either[Nothing, A]

 sealed trait Either[+E, +A] {

  def orElse[EE >: E, B](b: => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B]
    this match {
      case Left(_) => b              // error here
      case Right(a) => Right(a)
    }

}
```

I don't know what I meet error at `case Left(_) => b`:

> Cannot resolve symbol b

But this method will not throw error:

```
def orElse[EE >: E, AA >: A](b: => Either[EE, AA]): Either[EE, AA] =
  this match {
    case Left(_) => b
    case Right(a) => Right(a)
  }
```

Please tell me this.

Comment: The compiler is unable to resolve `b` because you forgot the `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jwvh stated in the comment, the you are missing an `=` in your definition:

```
def orElse[EE >: E, B](b: => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B] = ...
```

Without the `=`, the compiler sees an abstract `orElse` method and some random initialisation code, rather than an implemented method. Sometimes using braces helps get around cases like this

However after adding the = you get type errors because `B` must be related to `A` in `Either`, otherwise `this` won't match the passed value (similarly to how you got AA), leaving you with:

```
def orElse[EE >: E, B >: A](b: => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B] = ...
```

Replace the `B` with `AA` and you have your original working example

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I just learn scala, so I don't really see I miss "=" ;(